# How can i use svgr without breaking the nextjs static import

Tags: reactjs, svg, next.js, nextjs-image

I want to use some svg files as ReactComponent but i want to keep nextjs statically imported behavior. I tried the following methods and got no results.

Testing Code

```
import pen, { ReactComponent as Pen } from './pen.svg';
```

Normally in the nextjs, the import default result is like `{ src: string, width?: number, height?: number }`

next.config.js

```
/** @type {import('next').NextConfig} */
const nextConfig = {
  // ...
  webpack(config) {
    config.module.rules.push({
      test: /\.svg$/i,
      issuer: /\.[jt]sx?$/,
      use: [
        {
          loader: '@svgr/webpack',
          options: {
            exportType: 'named',
          },
        },
      ],
    });

    return config;
  },
};

module.exports = nextConfig;
```

When i use above config, default import is `undefined`.

next.config.js

```
/** @type {import('next').NextConfig} */
const nextConfig = {
  // ...
  webpack(config) {
    config.module.rules.push({
      test: /\.svg$/i,
      issuer: /\.[jt]sx?$/,
      use: ['@svgr/webpack', 'url-loader'],
    });

    return config;
  },
};

module.exports = nextConfig;
```

When i use above config, default import turning into `{ src: string }`. And i lose default width and height